# Quartz properties file configuration in web.xml and its location

Tags: quartz-scheduler, web.xml

I tried to resolve the problem of avoid loading default quartz.properties file for long time. Hope someone can give a hand here. Thanks a lot!

Basically, I have read many posts on this problem while their solutions didn't resolve my case. I have placed quartz.properties file under WEB-INF/classes and following are my configurations in web.xml by using context listener:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
    <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
   <param-name>quartz:wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
   <param-name>quartz:start-on-load</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>
       org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```

The results still showed like this:

```java
[INFO] 18 Feb 06:37:29.218 PM main [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory]
Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor

[INFO] 18 Feb 06:37:29.265 PM main [org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl]
Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl

[INFO] 18 Feb 06:37:29.265 PM main [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler]
Quartz Scheduler v.2.1.6 created.

[INFO] 18 Feb 06:37:29.265 PM main [org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore]
RAMJobStore initialized.

[INFO] 18 Feb 06:37:29.281 PM main [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler]
Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.1.6) 'MyQuartzTest' with instanceId       'NON_CLUSTERED'
Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
NOT STARTED.
Currently in standby mode.
Number of jobs executed: 0
Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 12 threads.
Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

[INFO] 18 Feb 06:37:29.281 PM main [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory]
Quartz scheduler 'MyQuartzTest' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'

[INFO] 18 Feb 06:37:29.281 PM main [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory]
Quartz scheduler version: 2.1.6

[INFO] 18 Feb 06:37:29.281 PM main [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler]
Scheduler MyQuartzTest_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.

[INFO] 18 Feb 06:37:29.312 PM MyQuartzTest_Worker-1  [org.quartz.examples.example1.HelloJob]
Hello World! - Mon Feb 18 18:37:29 GMT+08:00 2013

[INFO] 18 Feb 06:38:09.296 PM MyQuartzTest_Worker-2 [org.quartz.examples.example1.HelloJob]
Hello World! - Mon Feb 18 18:38:09 GMT+08:00 2013

[INFO] 18 Feb 06:38:29.296 PM main [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler]
Scheduler MyQuartzTest_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.

[INFO] 18 Feb 06:38:29.296 PM main [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler]
Scheduler MyQuartzTest_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.

[INFO] 18 Feb 06:38:29.296 PM main [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler]
Scheduler MyQuartzTest_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
```

Another confuse I have is if it was really loading default quartz.properties file, then why are the thread pool and scheduler name were set properly based on my customized quartz.properties file?

Another hand, I also tried to set different path for quartz.properties file based on the official documentation of Quartz: [QuartzInitializerListner](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerListener.html). For example:

```xml
<context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
     <param-value>/MyProject/WEB-INF/my_quartz.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The results showed even worse. It would be totally default settings. Hence, I'm quite lost now. Please kindly elaborate the root cause of this scenario. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue placing the *quartz.properties* in my resources folder (src/main/resources).

Your context Param should look like this:

```
<context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
     <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Take a look to the quartz's code:

```
InputStream is = null;
Properties props = new Properties();
is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

where *filename* is the properties file.

So, it tries to get the file as a Stream. Please check the Java Doc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

... have fun